# CodeIgniter 4, helper function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I've tried to autoload the helper function. I've added the helper file in autoload.php and called the function in the view file, but it's not working.

**app/Config/autoload.php**

```
$psr4 = ['Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
         APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH, 
         'App'         => APPPATH,
         'Helpers'     => APPPATH . 'Helpers/MY_helper'];
```

**app/Helpers/My_helper.php**

```
<?php  if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   function chicking_helper(){
       return 'welcome to helper function';
   }
```

**app/Views/welcome_message.php**

```
<h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter </h1>
<p class="version">version <?= CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter::CI_VERSION ?></p>

<?php
chicking_helper();
?>
```

**app/Controllers/BaseController**

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['url', 'file'];
```

Comment: You autoload code is incorrect. Try to use like $autoload['helped'] = array('functions');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BaseController - $helpers array, add an element with your helper filename. Say you have it as `app/Helpers/My_helper.php`, then you edit your BaseController like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['url', 'file', 'my_helper'];
```

You do not need to touch the Autoload class in your scenario. It is used to map all the different namespaces in your project.

**app/Helpers/My_helper.php**

```
if(!function_exists('chicking_helper')) {
       function chicking_helper(){
           return 'welcome to helper function';
       }
}
```

Codeigniter 4 documentation [helpers](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/helpers.html)

Comment: I got the error `Call to undefined function chicking_helper()`

Comment: Try protected $helpers = ['url', 'file', 'MY_helper'];
exactly like your filename is, may be capital letters are important

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure the PHP file has the correct naming. I had this problem also because my custom helper file was named "CustomHelper.php" under app/Helpers. After renaming it to "Custom_helper.php" it was possible to load it via the BaseController as mentioned before:

```
class BaseController extends Controller{
    //...
    protected $helpers = ['form', 'url','custom'];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this:
On your *app/Config/autoload.php* autoload array optional include the helper source. For attention every *_helper* is a suffix of each helper filemane.
So on *app/Controllers/BaseController* just add your prefix helper name: e.g: *chicking_helper.php*

```php
class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['form', 'html', 'chicking',];
.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the word '_helper' when declaring a new helper in BaseController.php. For instance:

```
class BaseController extends Controller{

    protected $helpers = ['url', 'file', 'my'];
```

will be looking to load a file named "my_helper.php" in app\Helpers.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are wrongly declared your helped functions in `autload.php`.

It must be declare something like this:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('file', 'url');
```

then in your controller or model, just call the helper function such as `default_method($parameter)`. The default_method is your helper function name.

Comment: I added the line in `autoload.php`. but not working. Any other possibilities

Comment: did you create the helper function in system/helpers or application/helpers directory? Please read this doc https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: Yes I created the files `app/Helpers/My_helper.php`.